# Mesh breaks rigging

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature

I have a watch strap that I'm trying to bend like in the image.
[image]

But the result is that the mesh is tearing apart.

[image]

What's the problem and how can I fix it?
The only thing I can think of is that I modeled the strap in rhino3d but I imported it correctly in Blender.
[image]

I followed this tutorial to rig: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l7AMm4Is2iY&vl=de
Is there a simpler solution to bend the strap like so?

If someone can help me I will appreciate it a lot.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its because that part of mesh is assigned to more than one bone
you can check it with selecting and deselecting different vertex groups and you see.

you can solve this by checking auto-normalize and substracting this parts from other vertex groups
[read about auto-normalize](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/weight_paint/tool_settings/options.html)
[image]
or you can just paint it again or instead of weight paint do it in edit mode and assigning by hand(this is good for simple meshes)
also I noticed your mesh is not connected some parts are separated so this is a good example of having a clean mesh could help clean rigging and animations

Comment: Thanks mma78, you saved me! Now it's working perfectly, just one question, how could you say that I have some parts separated?

Comment: first there is a gap between to parts of that mesh in second pic and when i downloaded it used L key to select linked vertexes

Comment: Thanks again! I resolved this problem doing: edit mode -> selected everything -> Mesh -> Clean up -> Merge by distance with 0.01